# How many tables can I have in 1 Sql Azure Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I know in Sql Server, Tables per database "Limited by number of objects in a database", "Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and constraints. The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot exceed 2,147,483,647."

My question is, whats the max number for the tables I can create in one Sql Azure Databse?

Thanks

Comment: change your question to: I need xxxxxxx, is that possible. Or even better, why not just try... It might take some time though:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remus is right!

And if you are on a study, better look for size limits, because the current maximum size of an SQL Azure database is 50 GB. Which means that if your database is larger than that, you'll have to wait for new bigger limits to become available. And this is defenitely something that is not changeble via a support ticket.

Other than that you can quickly check your database for SQL Azure compatability using the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard from CodePlex](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) - an easy to use SQL Server <-> SQL Azure migration tool.

Comment: Note that the max size is already on it's way to 150GB (Pending Q4SR deployment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/14/announcing-upcoming-sql-azure-q4-2011-service-release.aspx). This just proves the point that these limits are a moving target.

Comment: I know it already ;) but as you already mentioned it is "pending" ;) Not yet deployed to all servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself asking this question, then your plan is flawed. No sane design will need 2 billion objects in a database, or anything close to that.

The official [Guidelines and Limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394102.aspx) document mentions some of the limits supported (eg. 150 databases per server). The limit you are asking for is not documented.

Comment: Hi Remus, thank you for your reply. I do not have any plan yet, I just doing some study on migration from Sql Server to Sql Azure, therefor I have to know them both well, the limitation, the capacity is a very important number to know, do you agree. 

btw, the 150 databases is not a had limit, as you can email them and ask them increase.